# How do I use .htaccess rewrite to a cache subdirectory using the first letter of the request?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a caching program that creates static html files of dynamically generated php files. I currently use php to check if the cached version exists, if it does I serve it up and php exits. As in this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612735/using-mod-rewrite-to-view-cached-version-from-usual-url), I feel this is a waste of time. However, I have around 5,000 pages and as such, I would prefer not to place them all in the same /cache/ directory. I would instead like to place

```
/a-web-url/ in /cache/a/a-web-url.html.gz
```

and

```
/this-is-another-url/ in /cache/t/this-is-another-url.html.gz
```

I am currently working with

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_/\.]+)/$ /cache/$1
```

However this assumes that all are in the same directory. I would prefer them to be divided into subdirectories. Thanks.

Also note that all of my files end in .html.gz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?cache/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.)(.*?)/?$ /cache/${lc:$1}/${lc:$1}${lc:$2}.html.gz [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are matching more than one upper case, lower case, dashes and underscores with your current pattern. You can modify this to match just the first character using the same character class, and then the rest using the `+` modifier, and rewrite using the `$1` back reference for the first character and `$2` for the rest. Using `(!?cache/)` will prevent it from matching URLs that begin with `/cache/`.

```
RewriteRule ^(!?cache/)([A-Za-z0-9-_/\.])([A-Za-z0-9-_/\.]+)/$ /cache/$1/$1$2 [L]
```

You can test this rule here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

If you want to make the first character lower case you can add `RewriteMap tolower int:tolower` to your `<VirtualHost>` config and then use `${tolower:$1}` for the first character.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z])([A-Za-z0-9-_/\.]+)/$ /cache/$1/$1$2
```

Comment: If the file doesn't exist, will it skip this command and fallback on the index.php that generates the pages?

    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php