# Simple regex .htaccess using the first letter of a directory

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i need a simple rule htaccess. I just saw [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242456/how-do-i-use-htaccess-rewrite-to-a-cache-subdirectory-using-the-first-letter-of) but dosn't work for me.

For eg, i have this url:

```
http://img.myp.local/thumbs/640x700/Birra/nba_jordan_chicago.jpg
```

and i need to resolve this url:

```
/cache/Birra/B/nba_jordan_chicago640x700
```

where you can find:

```
 1. /cache/
 2. third directory
 3. first letter of third directory
 4. name of the file (without .jpg)
 5. second directory
```

At this time i wrote this rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/]+)/([^/]+).jpg?$ /cache/$2/${lc:$2}/$3$1 [L]
```

and the result is `/cache/Birra//nba_jordan_18640x700`  where you can see there is a missing FIRST LETTER OF THE THIRD DIRECTORY

thanks for your help,
stefano

**EDIT 1**
Adam's solution works great! but i have another question.

If the result `/cache/Birra/B/nba_jordan_chicago640x700` not exists, can i get another url? for eg. `/OTHER_DIRECTORY/640x700/Birra/nba_jordan_chicago.jpg`

grazie!

**EDIT 2**

guys this is the solution with the fallback:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$2/$3/$4$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(([^/])[^/]*)/([^/]+).jpg?$ /cache/$2/$3/$4$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$2/$3/$4$1 !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(([^/])[^/]*)/([^/]+).jpg?$ /thumbs/$1/$2/$4.jpg [L]
```

thank you again for your help

**EDIT 3**

@Adam: this works great for me:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$2/$3/$4$1 -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(([^/])[^/]*)/([^/]+).jpg?$ /cache/$2/$3/$4$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$2/$3/$4$1 !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(([^/])[^/]*)/([^/]+).jpg?$ /thumbs/$1/$2/$4.jpg [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @adam katz: thank you! it's work perfectly! you rock!

Comment: How does the **EDIT 2** solution work?  The `RewriteCond` matches don't correspond to anything...

Comment: hi @AdamKatz, take a look above (EDIT 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This captures the first letter *inside* the word so it can be used twice:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(([^/])[^/]*)/([^/]+).jpg?$ /cache/$2/$3/$4$1 [L]
```

If you want a fallback in the event that file does not exist, you can use [RewriteCond](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) with `-f`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/(([^/])[^/]*)/([^/]+).jpg?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%2/%3/%4%1 -f
RewriteRule /cache/%2/%3/%4%1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(([^/])[^/]*)/([^/]+).jpg?$ /OTHER_DIRECTORY/$2/$3/$4$1 [L]
```

This only goes to the `/cache` location when there is such a file and otherwise goes to `/OTHER_DIRECTORY`.  I'm rusty; I haven't done this sort of thing in years and I currently lack an Apache httpd instance with which to experiment, but this should be very close.

Comment: Adam any idea for the other question? (i edited the first question). Thank you

Comment: @user2568539, I have answered your other question, though I haven't tested my answer.  Let me know how it works.

Comment: Thank you Adam but it dosn't work. I mean: it always goes to OTHER_DIRECTORY also if the /cache/ file exists. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, without my own Apache httpd, I can't troubleshoot this efficiently.  Try it without the second `RewriteCond`, which should _always_ go to `/cache`.  If that works, then it's that removed line that is failing.  If it doesn't work, the first `RewriteCond` is the problem.

Comment: thank you Adam but it dosn't work. I deleted the second RewriteCond but always go to OTHER_DIRECTORY. Any ideas? really appreciate your help

Comment: Crap, that first `RewriteRule` should use percents rather than dollars so it can refer to the backreferences in the `RewriteCond`.  Try the current form, and if that doesn't work, try removing the second `RewriteCond`.  Don't forget to monitor your Apache logs for hints (if you have access).

Answer (score 1):

This might be better as it specifically ignores the first path component and adds a match for a literal '.' (rather than any character) at the end:

```
^                  # beginning of string
/                  # literal '/'
[^/]+?             # one or more chars except '/' - non-greedy
/                  # literal '/'
(                  # start capture group 1
  [^/]+?           # one or more chars except '/' - non-greedy
)                  # end capture group 1
/                  # literal '/'
(                  # start capture group 2
  (                # start capture group 3
  .                # first character
  )                # end capture group 3
  [^/]+?           # one or more chars except '/' - non-greedy
)                  # end capture group 2
/                  # literal '/'
(                  # start capture group 4
  .+?              # one or more chars - non-greedy
)                  # end capture group 4
\.                 # literal '.'
jpg                # literal 'jpg'
$                  # end of string
```

Thus:

```
RewriteRule ^/[^/]+?/([^/]+?)/((.)[^/]+?)/(.+?).jpg$ /cache/$2/$3/$4$1
```

Comment: The use of both '[^/]+' and '?' for non-greedy matching might on its face appear unnecessary, but it actually provides a useful hint to the Regular Expression engine which will help improve performance.

Comment: Hm. If you're always using a path like "/thumbs/640x700/Birra/nba_jordan_chicago.jpg" where there are always four parts of the path (i.e. [ 'thumbs', '640x700', 'Birra', 'nba_jordan_chicago.jpg' ] ) it will work. If you have more than four parts of the path, it will not.

Comment: Also, the previous solution will also match "/foo/bar/baz/thumbs/640x700/Birra/nba_jordan_chicagoXjpg" which might not be what you want.

Comment: Thank you Rob. It's clear now. Any idea for the other question? Grazie

Comment: I do not recommend lazy evaluators when they are not necessary.  They are very expensive.

Comment: @AdamKatz: You might wish to check out https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/06/03/why-using-in-regular-expressions-is-almost-never-what-you-actually-want which gives a cogent argument **for** using lazy evaluators, (i.e. `.+?` rather than `.*`)

Comment: @AdamKatz: Also, the Apache URL Rewriter uses the PCRE which is **notoriously** slow when backtracking.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the regular expression needs some adjustment:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*?)/([^/]*)/([^/])([^/]*)/([^/]+)\.jpg?$ /cache/$3$4/$3/$5$2 [L]
```

In: `http://img.myp.local/thumbs/640x700/Birra/nba_jordan_chicago.jpg`

Out: `http://img.myp.local/cache/Birra/B/nba_jordan_chicago640x700`

Tested on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be.

Comment: strange. It's work on madewithlove.be but it's donsn't work on my apache